# How change bintray package ownership

Tags: bintray

I maintain an open source [package](https://bintray.com/beta/#/dtanner/grails-plugins/jasypt-encryption) on bintray, and I'd like to transfer ownership of this to another person.
I presumed I could either directly transfer the package to another user, or move it into an organization, but don't see how to do either. Any docs or instructions on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two existing possibilities.

**Copy repository**
Your repository can be copied to another organization which you are a member of.

[image: copy repository]

**Transfer repository ownership**
You can transfer the ownership of the repository, if the repository is under an organization and the organization has members.

[image: Transfer repository]

NOTE: All are done with the old UI and not the new.